# How do I limit content type per role?

Tags: nodes, users, 5

I am running a Drupal 5 site with number of roles. Is there a way to assign limits per role? E.g. Authenticated user could upload 10 documents, whilst Paid user could upload 100 documents. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [NodeFamily module](http://drupal.org/node/268866) will allow setting a maximum number of nodes that can be created per user. However it doesn't provide per role maximum number settings.

Comment: Based on further discussions with Budda off line, we have decided to build a custom module to address this issue. I am closing the question.